# PHP - declare a global array

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I am having a problem of *Undefined variable* when I try to use an array inside a function. An example is the code below. How can I be able to access the array `$prev` inside the function `hello()`? I've tried searching but I don't really know how to use `$GLOBALS[$varname]` when the variable is an array. Thanks for any help!

```
<?php

$prev = [0,1,2];

function hello(){

    echo $prev[1];

}

hello();
hello();
hello();

?>
```

Comment: inside the function use `global $prev;` to make that var available.

Comment: but it would be better to pass that var to the function. Avoid using globals anytime possible.

Comment: Far better to learn about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and about how to [pass arguments to a function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: @Jeff what if at anytime I want to change the values inside the array (eg. i want to add 1 to the index 0) how would I do that if I pass the var to the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also pass the variable into the function:

```
$prev = [0,1,2];

function hello(array $array){

    echo $array[1];

}

hello($prev);
hello($prev);
hello($prev);

?>
```

An other way is to pass the variable [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

```
function hello(&$array){

    $array[1]++;
    echo $array[1];

}
```

Comment: this is great also however, what if at anytime I want to change the values inside the array (eg. i want to add 1 to the index 0) how would I do that if I pass the var to the function?

Comment: @Ralph If you want to change the value of it, just pass the parameter by reference. Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is the way to use it as global. Btw there are also other ways to use it inside the hello function.

```
$prev = [0,1,2];

function hello(){
    global $prev;

    echo $prev[1];

}

hello();
hello();
hello();
```

Comment: thank you for the fast reply! sorry I'm new to PHP but thank you so much!

Comment: global $prev; this means you declare a new array $prev which can access out side the function

Comment: @BunkerBoy no, it means that the outside array [is available in the function scope](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)

Comment: Thank you for this useful tip. Passing in arrays into functions isn't ideal sometimes. This fixed my issue very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
$GLOBALS["prev"] = [0,1,2];
function hello(){    
    echo $GLOBALS['prev'][1];    
}

hello();
```

However consider doing something like:

```
 $prev = [1,2,3];
 function hello($prev) {
      echo $prev[1];
 }
 hello($prev);
```

As an alternative solution:

```
class GlobalsContainer {
     public static $prev=[1,2,3];
}

function hello() {
     echo GlobalsContainer::$prev[1];
}
hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare array with `global` keyword inside the `function`. See it -

```
<?php

    function hello(){

        global $prev = [0,1,2];
        echo $prev[1];

    }


    ?>
```